# Can't create new calendar - no way to enter View List or List fields

Tags: list, sharepoint-calendar, share

I'm just trying to create an additional calendar and in the Create Overlay screen for the REQUIRED List and List View fields, there are no pull down options and no way to enter anything. Is this something I may be blocked from doing by our default company setup with Share? I am the administrator of the Share site.

Thanks!

Comment: You have no options to add overlays?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a correct web url and then click resolve, like in the following example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfwc8wQOk-c

If no list is shown then 
a.) the web does not contain a calendar
b.) the web could be broken or there could be a broken list